Wrapping function type with generics into a method
Edit:
As @jcalz points out, it is already answered in the related question that it is not possible to get return type of generic functions, so for the type of "wrapped method" as well.
I am trying to implement iterators similar to those in python and rust for typescript. As an attempt, I am splitting the methods/functions in functional approach and object-oriented Iter<T> class. For now, I have implemented most functions from python builtins and itertools, and am working on the class. However, it would be very repetitive and mechanical to just redirect all method calls to the functional approach, and I tried similar to the following:
export type Iterator<T> = IterableIterator<T> | T[];

export function* enumerate<T>(iter: Iterator<T>): Generator<[number, T]> {
    let i = 0;
    for(const item of iter) {
        yield [i, item];
        i++;
    }
}

export function* map<T, U>(iter: Iterator<T>, mapFn: (item: T) => U): Generator<U> {
    for(const item of iter) {
        yield mapFn(item);
    }
}

const generators = {enumerate, map};

type WrappedGenMethod<T, F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = 
    F extends (iter: Iterator<T>, ...args: infer Args) => Generator<infer U>
        ? (...args: Args) => Iter<U>
        : never;

/*
methods for generators
expected to be {
    enumerate: () => Iter<[number, T]>,
    map: <U>(mapFn: (item: T) => U) => Iter<U>
}
*/
type Gen<T> = {
    [key in keyof typeof generators]: WrappedGenMethod<T, typeof generators[key]>
}

export class Iter<T> implements IterableIterator<T> {
    // not really related
    private inner: IterableIterator<T>
    private consumed = false;

    [Symbol.iterator] = () => this.inner;

    constructor(from: Iterator<T>) {
        this.inner = from[Symbol.iterator]();
    }

    next() {
        return this.inner.next();
    }

    consume() {
        if (this.consumed) throw new Error("Iterator already consumed!");
        this.consumed = true;
    }
}

export interface Iter<T> extends Gen<T> {}

Iter.prototype.enumerate = function() {
    this.consume();
    return new Iter(generators.enumerate(this))
}

// Commented out since the compiler cannot determine T

// Iter.prototype.map = function<U>(mapFn: (item: T) => U) {
//     this.consume();
//     return new Iter(generators.map(this, mapFn))
// }

const res = new Iter([1,2,3,4]).enumerate();

... and then I can modify the prototype by iterating keys of generators and accumulators.
However, the generics are all inferred as unknown. For example, res has type Iter<[number, unknown]> whereas the functional implementation has signature function* enumerate<T>(iter: Iterator<T>): Generator<[number, T]> and new Iter([1,2,3,4]).map(i=>(i as number)*2) also has type Iter<unknown>, and i is passed in as unknown as well.
Are there any workarounds? I would be very grateful!

@jcalz Thank you for your kind comment. I have edited my post accordingly.

TS doesn't have the higher order generics required for WrappedGenMethod to work the way you want. What type do you expect Gen<T> to be? Can you write it out manually (at least to make it clear what you expect)?  Is it this?

@jcalz Yes. Sorry about not updating the code in time.

So, it's not possible, see this question/answer. You're going to have to write Gen<T> out manually every time you update generators, or give up entirely. Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?

@jcalz Yes, I think that answers my question, thank you!
